# Personal wiki on usb / the cloud?

Tags: software-rec, wiki

I'm looking for a personal wiki that can be installed on an usb stick and (more importantly) somewhere on the cloud (dropbox). I've looked at the [Wiki Matrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/), but I really don't care that much about any of the options, so I end up with a choice between ~50 wikis at the end. Tried out TiddlyWiki but there are some things that really annoy me like the fact that all pages get opened on the same page. It really looks like it'd turn into a giant mess pretty quickly.

I'd like to have something that's pretty close in terms of appearance and usability to wikipedia. Hierarchical categories for organization would be really nice. And accessible storage (in case I ever want to convert it to something else).

Answer (score 2):

If none of the offers in the Wiki Matrix interests you, then maybe a Wiki is not for you after all.

I use [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com) as my personal wiki - it has a USB installation, as well as an Internet service that does regular syncing.

Super-powerful, it supports fast clipping of information from many sources. It is also available on various desktop and mobile platforms. It has an easy access web-interface. Gina Trapani of Lifehacker fame [has switched to Evernote as her own personal wiki](http://smarterware.org/2197/david-pogues-personal-database) - and you should give it a shot too.

Comment: Oh, they do interest me. It's just that I'm left with too many options. I don't want to try out 50 different wikis if I can help it.

Comment: +1 I agree with scoopdreams. I use Evernote and love it.

Answer (score 2):

[Tiddlywiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) is a single file wiki, so you can easily use it with dropbox

a variant on this is [MPTW](http://mptw.tiddlyspot.com/) formerly know as MonkeyPirateTiddlyWiki, it includes some plugins and has a bit different approach to organizing

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming you use windows (though there's likely an equivilent for OS X or linux) why not run a portable WAMP (i believe xampp runs portably stack on the thumb drive, and run mediawiki on it, if what you want is mediawiki, essentially?

Answer (score 1):

There's [DokuWiki on a Stick](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2008-05/16-dokuwiki_on_a_stick_2008-05-05).  I've run DokuWiki before, but I've never tried the portable version.  This should work with DropBox since it stores its data in flat files instead of a database.

[PBWiki](http://pbworks.com/) is a hosted wiki solution that you might want to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/MoinMoinWiki)'s ["Desktop Mode"](http://moinmo.in/DesktopEdition) for this purpose.  As long as Python is installed, you just run the included `wikiserver.py` file to start serving the wiki to your local machine at `http://localhost:8080/`.

I store my wiki in a [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) volume, and use [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/) to sync it between my Windows and Mac computers.  If you have/can run Python on the machines where you'll be using the wiki, I think MoinMoin's features and simplicity will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [ConnectedText](http://www.connectedtext.com/), which has a portable version ([see FAQ for more](http://www.connectedtext.com/faqusb.html#P1)).  It supports categorization in the same manner as Mediawiki, plus has a handful of useful plugins (LaTeX, Ploticus, Graphviz) and supports scripting.  It is a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to do is get a note-taking app, which would allow you to insert links to other notes within one database. [CintaNotes](http://cintanotes.com/download/) is one such app.
Basically, it's a simple notes manager, which supports links to web-pages, local files and notes. From where I'm standing it looks like this should totally be enough for a personal wiki. To get the wiki on you usb drive you're gonna have to use the portable version of the app.

Kind regards