# Wiki on a pendrive - should work with any OS

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, portable, wiki

I want to have an "extended memory" and want to accomplish that with an wiki on an pendrive. I already decided to use PmWiki, but if another wiki solves my problem that would be fine.

The issue is: If I install an Apache on an pendrive, it depends on the running operating system. Because I'm using Windows & Linux (and will use Mac in the future) it is crucial for me to be platform independent.

I read [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/37619/personal-wiki-on-usb-the-cloud). DokuWiki is for Windows only and MoinMoin needs Python installed (which would be possible on my PCs, but not on public ones).

Every help for my "extended memory" is appreciated.

PS: As a last resort I could host a wiki on my webpage, which would be accessible everywhere. But I just see a challenge in trying it on a pendrive.

Answer (score 5):

A few years ago I played with [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/).  It should meet your needs; no Apache required, no database required.

Comment: Thanks very much, exactly what I was looking for. :) Their suggestion to use an portable browser is really good, too.

Comment: One limitation that I've run across is that on some locked down enterprise systems, you can't save changes in Chrome.   For some reason it still works in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use text files and store in a good directory structure on the pen drive - then you are ensured in will work everywhere and anywhere!

After that, you may be out of luck - most Wiki (well everyone I have seen) require a database and web server - I just don't see how you will achieve this cross platform.

You will have to download Apache + Mysql for each platform and after that, Apache config requires a hard path (Someone please say if I am wrong) to the home folder - obviously this will be different on each OS (no problem, different config files) but it could also have different drive letters which can be a nightmare.

I think the best thing you can probably do, if set on going down the wiki route, is configure and install it within a light weight Linux virtual machine on VirtualBox, and have the VirtualBox install files on the USB stick. I know you can get a portable Virtualbox fr Windows, I am not sure about Linux + OSX.

I hope this helps, but I think it is the only real practical solution.