# Portable Wiki which stores .txt or HTML files

Tags: portable, blogging, wiki

I know there are TiddlyWiki but I need one which stores HTML or even .txt files.

I want to use this Wiki like a personal blog, i want to log my life (probably cringy to you) and things I've done, programmed etc.

I want to be abled to carry this wiki on my USB so I can just plug into any computer and wiki away.

Comment: You might find something in this previous Q&A: http://superuser.com/questions/37619/personal-wiki-on-usb-the-cloud

Comment: tiddlywiki *does* store itself locally using html files, is there some feature that it is lacking?

Comment: I already did a search but didn't find anything (for me). And that was posted in 2009 so there might be new apps which I haven't been able to find for myself. :)

@Mokubai Tiddlywiki is just a big mess for me, opens everything on same page and can't seem to get hang of it. I don't like the usablity of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched under the similar situation and tested TiddlyWiki.  However, it doesn't my needs so that I develop [Juli](http://jjjuli.sourceforge.net/).  While Juli is still evolving, I found http://ikiwiki.info/ , this also may be a good for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking around and I have found [Wiki On A Stick](http://stickwiki.sourceforge.net/index.html) which appears to be a simple downloadable browser-based Wiki that modifies it's own files.

One feature I like the look of is that it claims to support [AES 256 encryption](http://stickwiki.sourceforge.net/woas__help__security.html) of pages so while it is stored on a memory stick your individual posts could be well protected.  Potentially a plus if you are keeping personal data in there.

Answer (score 1):

[Zim Desktop Wiki](http://zim-wiki.org) deserves your consideration, I have used it for almost one year, and find it simple, flexible and reliable.

1. It does store wiki notes in .txt file format.
2. It make use of Windows/Linux directory as namespace.
3. You can export one page or the whole wiki to static html files.
4. It does have a [Portable Version](http://www.glump.net/software/zim-windows) for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/).

Although is is primarily a version control systems it also includes a simple Wiki. You can keep the files external as plain html files (with simple wiki-markup) or store the files within a single (data)file.

The most charming aspect: it is only a single executable of about 1 MB that includes everything you need (webserver, SQLite database, wiki-server). There is no need to install anything, just run the executable. Period.